# File missing after recompile

Tags: dart, flutter

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1i2l.png)
When compiling my file I get the following error: `library is in a package that is not known`

This is referring to the file: home.dart under my pages folder.

These are [my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLsS2.png) on the pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependecies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: "^0.12.0+1"
  intl: "^0.15.8"
  charts_flutter: "0.6.0"
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbHaK.png):

```
import 'package:fLutter/materiaL.dart';
import 'package:charts_fLutter/fLutter.dart' as charts

class PieChart extends StatefulWidget {
final Widget child;
override
PieChart({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
_PieChartState createState() => _PieChartState();


class GPieChartState extends State<PieChart> {
List<charts.Series<Effl,String>> _seriesPieData;
_generateData() {
var        pieData = [
new Effl( ' > ObJectlf ' , 35.8, Colors.bZue[6oo]),
new Effl( ' < ObJectlf ' , 8.3, Colors.red[6oo]),
```

Comment: What if you use `charts_flutter: ^0.6.0` and then re-get dependencies

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take the time to paste the text instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so looking at the error it says

> `Refers, in an import, to the following library:
>   package:efficience001/pages/home.dart
>   That library is in a package that is not know. Maybe you forgot to mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?`

This means Flutter didn't manage to find the file home.dart under the pages directory.

Since you say that it worked before, the only possible logical explanation is that you have renamed, deleted, or moved the file "home.dart" or its parent folder.